# Where can I find the download files from the emulator Leapdroid on my PC's folders?

Tags: windows, android-emulator

I download some picturs on my Android emulator Leapdroid from an application ! 
I found them on my emulator but where can I find them on my computer's folders !

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible to do. But you can copy/transfer them to/from windows:

Using Shared folders on Leapdroid, you can copy files to windows folder.

On Windows open: AppData\Roaming\leapdroid\shared.
On Android: /mnt/shared/yw_shared.

Using the procedure I was able to transfer all my Whatsapp data to my Windows folders, --more than 1GB-- , it's a little bit slow but it works!!

Review this link for other option:

[How can I transfer files from my PC to my Leapdroid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860968/how-can-i-transfer-files-from-my-pc-to-my-leapdroid)