# How can I transfer files from my PC to my Leapdroid?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I transfer files like picturs and music from my PC to My android emulator (Leapdroid) ?
And how can I find the files those are in my Android emulator (Leapdroid) in my PC ?

Answer (score 4):

shared folders, you can copy files to windows foder, AppData\Roaming\leapdroid\shared, then inside Android, it's in /mnt/shared/yw_shared

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully completed this task using es file explorer and transferring via lan.

Comment: PLease explain more

Answer (score 1):

Download es file explorer on Leapdroid. then open it and go to network > LAN. Scan for devices and connect to your PC. there u can transfer files

Answer (score 1):

It's easy just go to %appdata%/roaming/ there you will found an abstract folder,in my case it was "yiwanzhushou",It may vary in your case,then inside that go to shared folder and put your files in there. Next go to es file explorer in leapdroid  and then inside it goto mnt/shared/ywshared there you will find your files.................................

Answer (score 0):

### How to Transfer Data from PC to Leapdroid:

1) Install EZ file manger in Leapdroid.
2) Scan LAN network. You will see the connected drives of the PC as:
   10.0.3.x,  10.0.3.y and  10.0.3.z.
3) The first link is C drive. To get access to it, put your login and pswd.
   Login: {Your Windows Login ID}
   pswd: {Your Windows Login pswd}
  That is it. Enjoy.